# how to use cordova plugin InAppBrowser in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

Im trying to create a cordova app with angular 4. Now i have to use InAppBrowser into my app. i have installed the plugin into the cordova, but how can i use it into the angular 4?

I have tried with [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) this documentation, but I couldn't complete it. 
and code like

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

1. how to import InAppBrowser into the angular 4 project
2. how to use it ?